# Is there an example for two subsets A and B of the Reals such that cardinality A = card B and card (R-A) does not equal card( R-B )

Tags: examples-counterexamples, cardinals

Or is there no example in which the cardinalities are not equal?

Comment: Let $A',B'$ be any two finite sets with different cardinalities and let $A=\mathbb{R}-A',B=\mathbb{R}-B'$ Another way: Let $A'$ be finite and $B'$ countably infinite.

Comment: But the cardinalities of A, B must be equal I believe ?

Comment: Try the complements of two different sized finite sets.

Answer (score 2):

Take  $\;A=\Bbb R\;,\;\;B=Irr=\;$ the irrationals. Then $\;|A|=|B|=2^{\aleph_0}\;$, yet $\;\Bbb R\setminus A=\emptyset\;,\;\;\Bbb R\setminus B=\Bbb Q\ldots\;$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It can be done with sets $A$ and $B$ that both have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ itself.